# Powershell Disable Anonymous FTP and Enable Authentication

Tags: powershell, iis, ftp

Trying to do something fairly simple in PowerShell. Disable Anonymous FTP on the default ftp site and enable basic authentication like so: [FTP Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtGrA.png).

Here's what I"m trying:

```
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:anonymousAuthentication
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config /section:basicAuthentication
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name Enabled -value false -PSPath 'IIS:\sites\Default FTP Site\'
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication -name Enabled -value true -PSPath 'IIS:\sites\Default FTP Site\'
```

This succeeds with:

```
Unlocked section "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" at configuration path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST".
Unlocked section "system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication" at configuration path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST".
```

But it has no effect on the actual IIS configuration at all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this command line. It will disable anonymous authentication and enable basic authentication. Just remember to run powershell as administrator.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default FTP Site']/ftpServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "enabled" -value "False"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default FTP Site']/ftpServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication" -name "enabled" -value "True"
```